# CakePHP How to know user type with model relationship

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this relationships in CakePHP 2.6.x

```
                                | -- ProfessorUser
Project -- ProjectUser -- User  |
                                | -- StudentUser
```

**Database**
[image: db]

**Project Model**

```
public $hasMany = array('ProjectUser');
```

**ProjectUser Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

**Result**

> $this->Project->Find('all', array('recursive' => 2));

```
'ProjectUser' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'project_id' => '1',
                'user_id' => '2',
                'User' => array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'name' => 'John',
                        ....
                )
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '18',
                'project_id' => '1',
                'user_id' => '1',
                'User' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'name' => 'Kate',
                        ....
                )
            )
```

**My question**

Ok I have users assigned to project BUT how I know if user is Professor or Student?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `hasOne()` relation to your User model:

```
var $hasOne = array ('ProfessorUser', 'StudentUser')
```

Then, check if the User object has a valid ProfessorUser or StudentUser sub-object (that is, a non-empty array).

It may be worthwhile to add a column to User to indicate the user type. Right now a User can have both a ProfessorUser and StudentUser record, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: thanks for comment. No changes adding $hasOne. No sub-object present on object. Why? I have been thinking about add user type to users table. You right :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to increase your recursion level (with the risk of a data explosion, but alas...)